# how impelent php include (function) in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I know a little php and django.
When I writing blog in php, I make a file for my functions. for example a function for 10 new post, a function for top visited posts and etc. then I use these function in side bar.

I can get same result in django when using standard view. But when I using generic class view I can not pass top or new post to template?
Is there a technique to include them to template and generate them automatically in template with out passing them from view?
How you do stuff like this in django?

Comment: From what I understand, the best approach may be to use [custom template tags or filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to write [template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). For example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('results.html')
def show_results(poll):
    choices = poll.choice_set.all()
    return {'choices': choices}
```

You can then include results of a poll by writing in the template:

```
{% show_results poll %}
```

The documentation explains it in more detail but a similar approach can be used to display the top posts and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
{% include 'foo/bar.html' }
```

If you need to parametrize it, you need to declare an inclusion template tag and call it.

Answer (score 0):

[Include Documentation Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include 'reusablecode.html' %}
```

the code should be like this